# optimization of a function with inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have a function to be maximized subject to constraints. I can write the primal Lagrange function as the following: (objective function WITH two constraints in the last two terms)

$$L_P = \frac{1}{2} ||\beta||^2 + C\sum_{i=1}^N \xi_i - \sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i[y_i(x_i^T\beta + \beta_0)-(1-\xi_i)] - \sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i \xi_i$$

So, as usual, I took the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial L_P}{\partial \beta} = 0$, $\frac{\partial L_P}{\partial \beta_0} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial L_P}{\partial \xi_i} = 0$, and we have the following results:

$$\beta = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_iy_ix_i$$

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_iy_i$$

$$\alpha_i = C - \mu_i $$

Finally, I attempted to get the last three equations and plug them into $L_P$ to complete the optimization, and I don't know what to do anymore. The final result should be:

$$L_D = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N\alpha_i \alpha_{i'}y_iy_{i'}x_i^Tx_{i'}$$

Comment: You mention an equality constraint but you haven't told us what it is. If you want help here my suggestion is that you provide the original model, *before* the Lagrangian is constructed.

Comment: This is from the support vector classifier in statistical learning.

Comment: Fine. You should still put the model in the question.